# Whiplash short movie from Sundance 2013

Tags: soundtrack

Recently I've seen the [Whiplash](http://www.amoveocompany.com/damien-chazelle/) short movie. And I really like the music they're playing.

**Question**: Is the music a real musical composition or was it specially written for the movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it by myself: that's a **Whiplash** composition written by Hank Levy and the most popular play is by Don Ellis Orchestra.